# Sql Select value in From Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a tricky time doing this so hopefully someone can help. This is what I want my end result to be:

```
SELECT  'PRODUCT' AS ItemType, 
    'x' + CAST(MB_StaticOrderProducts.Quantity AS varchar(50)), 
     MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductName + ' (' + CAST((MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductSize) AS varchar(50)) + ' ' + MB_StaticProductMeasure.Value + ')' AS Name, 
     MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductSizeID,
     GTIN as BarCode
 FROM 
     MB_StaticOrderProducts 
 INNER JOIN MB_StaticOrderVersions ON MB_StaticOrderProducts.StaticOrderVersionId = MB_StaticOrderVersions.StaticOrderVersionId 
     INNER JOIN MB_StaticProductMeasure ON MB_StaticOrderProducts.StaticProductMeasureId = MB_StaticProductMeasure.StaticProductMeasureId 
 Inner Join ProductVariantAttributeCombination pvac on (pvac.Id = (select id  from (select Id, cast(AttributesXml as xml) data from ProductVariantAttributeCombination) d cross apply data.nodes('//ProductVariantAttributeValue[Value[1] = 32]') data(d)))
  WHERE 
      MB_StaticOrderProducts.StaticOrderVersionId = '8D803EAE-2CFC-455C-9CE7-0849618E1548'
```

I would like the column, MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductSizeId to be in the 4th line of the From section, ProductVariantAttributeCombination, where the number 32 is. Is there a way to use the variable in that area?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1):

For those that ever need it. I changed the data.nodes line to be:

```
data.nodes( '//ProductVariantAttributeValue[Value[1]
              =sql:column("MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductSizeID")]')
```

and all worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Concat function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

Like this:

```
data.nodes( concat('//ProductVariantAttributeValue[Value[1] = ',
                    MB_StaticOrderProducts.ProductSizeId, 
                   ']')
```

Comment: I get this error, "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal"